Leaking basement under chimney - weep hole solution?
We have a brick chimney that rests on a basement foundation wall about 2' above grade (basement is 2/3 below ground). We have a trickle leak into our basement after heavy rains below the the back right corner of the chimney (opposite corner you see in this first picture (the leak is not where the broken cement is)).

Years ago, I redid the cement lip around the foundation wall where the brick rests on the foundation wall. You can see in the prior photo that it is starting to break up, so I'm going to redo it. The cement breaking up is not the cause of the leak. I've come to realize over time that when I redid this cement lip before, I covered up some or all of the weep holes accidentally, which I believe is the cause of the small leak. Live and learn there. Here is a photo of the original weep holes.

This is what it looks like now (we are now looking at the corner near the basement leak), with weep holes covered up...

I'm going to redo this cement lip properly, using Weep Shield weep hole covers in the mortar around the chimney.
With that said... my question is, because I need to build up the cement lip about 1" to run water away from the brick on the exterior of the chimney, if my new weep holes are at the 1" height of the cement lip on the exterior, will water still get trapped inside the chimney, because there is no cement lip on the inside of the brick and any trapped water will just be sitting there? Or are weep holes mainly for ventilation and not channels for water to disperse?



Your sketch assumes that there is no equivalent filler on the interior.  Are the holes big enough to push an inspection camera through?

Just a weekend warrior here.
But, correct. My sketch assumes the worst case scenario. But since I’m the one who created the new lip several years ago, I have no idea if it’s the same height as one that is potentially on the inside as well. The camera thing is a good idea. As it currently stands, there are no more weep poles. They were mortared over on the last fix. But, once I have a good game plan for installing the new weep holes, they will probably be an inch and a half tall and as wide as the mortar crack.
